# Very simple Python RPG

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x, role-playing-game

I am new to Python and am working on a small RPG game project to practice the language and OOP. I honestly don't know what I am doing though, so before I get into developing the battle system I figured I would first show my code so far in, case I'm making a big mess!

Implemented so far:

- Save/Load game
- Player can choose a team to play (and is able to change the team afterwards, whenever he wants)
- Player can see his team's stats (character names, level, moves)

main.py

```
import jsonpickle
import os
import sys
from world import World
from player_team import Player_team

# Initialization 
world = World()
player_team = Player_team()
SAVEGAME_FILENAME = 'rpg_lqsa.json'
game_state = dict()     

def save_game():
    global game_state
    with open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, 'w') as savegame:
        savegame.write(jsonpickle.encode(game_state))

def load_game():
    with open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, 'r') as savegame:
        state = jsonpickle.decode(savegame.read())
    return state

def menu():

    # Display menu
    print ("***MENU***\n")
    print ("1. Fight")
    print ("2. Team")
    print ("3. Exit")

    choice = input("\Command: ")
    validate_choice(choice, 1, 3)

    # Battle
    if choice == '1':
        print()

    # Team submenu    
    elif choice == '2':
        team_menu()

    # Save and exit game
    elif choice == '3':
        save_game()
        print("\nGame saved automatically. Bye!")
        sys.exit(0)

    else:
        print ("\nUnexpected error occurred.")
        sys.exit(0)

def team_menu():

    # Display team submenu
    print ("\n***TEAM SUBMENU***\n")
    print ("1. Show team stats")
    print ("2. Switch team")

    choice = input("\Comman: ")
    validate_choice(choice, 1, 2)

    # Show team stats
    if choice == '1':
        player_team.display_team()
        input()

    # Change player's team
    elif choice == '2':
        print()
        choose_team()

    else:
        print ("\nUnexpected error occurred.")
        sys.exit(0)

def validate_choice(choice, first_num, last_num):
    error_message = '\nYou should provide a number between {} and {}.'.format(first_num, last_num)

    while True:    
        if choice.isdigit():
            if int(choice) not in range(first_num, last_num+1):
                print (error_message)
                choice = input()
            else:
                break   
        else:
            print (error_message)
            choice = input()  

def choose_team():

    # Display available teams
    print("Pick a team:\n")

    for index, team in enumerate(world.teams):
        print ('{}. {} y {}'.format(index+1, team[0].name, team[1].name))

    choice = input("\Command: ")
    validate_choice(choice, 1, len(world.teams))

    # Add team
    chosen_team = world.teams[int(choice)-1]
    player_team.set_team(chosen_team[0], chosen_team[1])

    # Save player team
    global game_state
    game_state['player_team'] = player_team

    # Team added
    print("\nDone! Your new team is ready to kick ass. Good luck!")
    input()

def new_game():

    # Introduction
    introMessage = (
        '\nVirtual Reality arrived to Montepinar '
        'and our dear neighbors decided to create '
        'a fighting tournament during the next month.\n'
        'The winner couple will earn 3 quotes as a price. Let's start!')
    print(introMessage)
    input()

    # First player team
    choose_team()

    # Show menu loop
    run_game()

def start_menu():
    global game_state
    global player_team

    while True:
        print("***RPG La Que Se Avecina***\n")
        print("1. New game")
        print("2. Load game")
        print("3. Exit")

        choice = input("\Command: ")
        validate_choice(choice, 1, 3)

        # New game
        if choice == '1':
            if not os.path.isfile(SAVEGAME_FILENAME):
                game_state["player_team"] = player_team
                new_game()
                return False
            else:
                answer = input("\nThere's a save game. Do you want to overwrite it and start again? ('yes' to confirm)\n\n")
                if answer.lower() == 'yes':
                    new_game()
                    return False
                print()

        # Load game
        elif choice == '2':
            if not os.path.isfile(SAVEGAME_FILENAME):
                print("\nNo saved games.")
                input()
            else:
                game_state = load_game()
                print()
                run_game()
                return False

        # Exit game
        elif choice == '3':
            print("\nBye!")
            sys.exit(0)
            return False

        else:
            print ("\nUnexpected error occurred.")
            sys.exit(0) 
            return False   

# Game loop
def run_game():

    global game_state
    global player_team

    # Load player's team
    player_team = game_state["player_team"]

    while True:

        # Menu loop
        menu()

# Start with New/Load game
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_menu()
```

character.py

```
import random

class Character:

    def __init__(self, name, moves = None, combos = None):
        if moves == None:
            moves = []
        if combos == None:
            combos = []
        self.name = name
        self.moves = moves
        self.combos = combos
        self.partner = None
        self.health = 1000
        self.max_health = 1000
        self.exp_points = 0
        self.level = 1

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.health > 0

    def get_move_names(self):
        move_names = ""
        for move in self.moves:
            move_names += "{} ({}), ".format(move.name, move.level)
        move_names = move_names.rstrip(', ')
        return move_names

    # User interface   
    def do_damage(self, move, rival):
        move.damage = random(0, 100 * move.level)

        if move.damage == 0: 
            print ("{} avoided attack from {}!".format(rival.name, self.name))
        else: 
            print ("{} did {} damage to {}.".format(self.name, move.damage, rival.name))
        return rival.health <= 0
```

lqsa_character.py

```
from character import Character
from move import Move

class Lqsa_character:
    Antonio = Character("Antonio", moves = [Move("Centollazo"), Move("Calambrazo")])
    Enrique = Character("Enrique", moves = [Move("Dialog"), Move("Ataque2")])
    Fermin = Character("Fermín", moves = [Move("Kick"), Move("Hit")])
    Vicente = Character("Vicente", moves = [Move("Controller hit"), Move("Salto Suicida")])
    Amador = Character("Amador", moves = [Move("Pinchito"), Move("Cabezazo")])
    Teodoro = Character("Teodoro", moves = [Move("Pinchito"), Move("Cabezazo")])
    Javi = Character("Javi", moves = [Move("Golpe de Ansiolíticos"), Move("Ataque2")])
    Lola = Character("Lola", moves = [Move("Attack1"), Move("Attack2")])

    def __init__(self):
        self.assignPartners()

    def assignPartners(self):
        self.Antonio.partner = self.Enrique
        self.Enrique.partner = self.Antonio
        self.Fermin.partner = self.Vicente
        self.Vicente.partner = self.Fermin
        self.Amador.partner = self.Teodoro
        self.Teodoro.partner = self.Amador
        self.Javi.partner = self.Lola
        self.Lola.partner = self.Javi
```

move.py

```
class Move:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.level = 1
        self.damage = 0
```

item.py

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, name, quantity, price):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price   
        self.utility = ""

    def display_info(self, item):
        return "{} - Units: {}, Utility: {}".format(item.name, item.quantity, item.utility)
```

player_team.py

```
from item import Item

class Player_team:

    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.inventory = []

    def set_team(self, character1, character2):
        self.members = [character1, character2]        

    def is_alive(self):
        for member in self.members:
            if member.health > 0:
                return True
        return False

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.inventory.append(item)

    # User Interface

    def display_team(self):
        if len(self.members) <= 0 or self.members[0] == None or self.members[1] == None:
            raise Exception("Unexpected error occurred.")

        print ("\n***Team***\n")
        for member in self.members:
            print("-> {} ({})\n   Moves: [{}]\n".format(member.name, member.level, member.get_move_names()))

    def display_inventory(self):
        for item in self.inventory:
            print(Item.display_info(item), '\n')
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Neat project, I wish I knew Spanish, but this is a fun way to learn for sure!

Comment: Moved most of spanish words to english, should be more understandable now

Interesting project btw, about an important part of spanish folklore :)

Comment: Is translating code into English an exception to the rule of never editing the code in a question? Even though it certainly helps getting more answers, I can imagine there might be valid points about the original that get lost in translation. Also, coding in English might be one of the most important suggestions in a review.

Answer (score 6):

> Welcome to Code Review. This is a really awesome piece of program you
>   have :) And thanks to [A. Romeu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/99376/a-romeu) for translations.

Because I noticed the awkward syntax highlighting towards the end of `main.py` here around `introduction` section; I would suggest [**multi-line strings**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/1190388); which is simply wrapping it all in triple-quotes.

> [image]

```
    # Introduction
    introMessage = """
Virtual Reality arrived to Montepinar
and our dear neighbors decided to create
a fighting tournament during the next month.

The winner couple will earn 3 quotes as a price. Let's start!
"""
    print(introMessage)
    input()
```

---

Naming conventions should be consistent throughout the project, and with [Python's PEP-8 RFCs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), you have it:

- variables and methods are named in `snake_lower_case`
- class names are defined as `CamelUpperFirstCase`

So it will be `PlayerTeam`, `assign_partners` etc.

> Following this makes your code really easy to read for fellow
>   pythoners. If you violate these conventions, the worst you'll get is
>   some dirty looks

---

Avoid using `global` variables references inside functions. Pass them as arguments instead (referring to `global game_state`; `global player_team` etc.).

---

Ideal import order ([according to PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)) is

- standard library imports
- related third party imports
- local application/library specific imports

`os`/`sys` etc. are standard library, and should be imported first, followed by `jsonpickle` and lastly placing `world` and `team`.

---

Try to use [`docstrings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for functions/class definitions. It helps in maintaining your application over a long course of time.

---

Your `item` class can be replaced by a simple [`namedtuple`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/collections#collections.namedtuple), and overriding the `__str__` method is really easy.

```
Item = namedtuple('Item', "name, quantity, price, utility")
Item.__str__ = lambda item: f"{item.name} - Units: {item.quantity}, Utility: {item.utility}"
```

However, it might not be the case as there could be some methods that might need to be introduced to particular items. Still, `__str__` method is to be noted.

---

[Checking for `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11166748/1190388) should be done with `is` and `is not` instead of `==` checks.

> Something can not be equal to nothing.

---

You should also implement a stricter check against a character's moves. They should all be an instance of `Move` class.

```
assert all(isinstance(move, Move) for move in moves)
```

---

```
def get_move_names(self):
    move_names = ""
    for move in self.moves:
        move_names += "{} ({}), ".format(move.name, move.level)
    move_names = move_names.rstrip(', ')
    return move_names
```

can be rewritten as:

```
def get_move_names(self):
    return ", ".join([str(move) for move in self.moves])
```

and in your `Move` class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{} ({})".format(self.name, self.level)
```

---

Your current `validate_choice` takes the first input and a range of integer valid values. This can be improved

```
def validate_choice(prompt, valid_values):
    error_message = "Valid values are: " + ', '.join((str(x) for x in valid_values))
    while True:
        choice = input(prompt)
        if choice in valid_values:
            return choice
        else:
            print(error_message)
```

and usage is really simple, instead of:

```
choice = input("\Command: ")
validate_choice(choice, 1, 3)
```

you now have:

```
choice = validate_choice("Command: ", list(range(1, 4)))
```

The benefit of this style is, you can also support:

```
choice = validate_choice("Command: ", 'A', 'B', 'E', 'X')
```

---

> I do not understand why you have a `Lqsa_character` class.

Comment: I mainly program in English but since this RPG game is based on a Spanish TV show it wouldn't really make sense. I tried to write everything logic related in English though. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks A. Romeu for the translations! @hjpotter92, I don't know how to thank you enough for such a great answer! The class "lqsa_character" is meant just for generating the tv show characters. Where should I create them (and assign their partners) instead? In world.py maybe? or character.py? I had doubts about it so I just made a new class, but now I'm not sure what's best. :S

Comment: @Guest43242 The reason you can't accept an answer is because you have created duplicate accounts, the question was asked with one account but now you are using another. I have asked the community team to merge these accounts so that you should be able to accept the answer.